# CAML Query of List's Lookup Field

Tags: jquery, list-view, caml-query

I have a child form and I want to get the total of the child forms to update the parent with the sum total. I am struggling with the CAML query to get the total back. The below returns zero records at present because (i suspect) the query isn't quite right.

```
        var query = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Engagement" /><Value Type="Lookup">';
            query += ParentEngagementID + ";#" + ParentEngagementText + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";


        console.log("Query is " + query);
        //Checked in chrome this is: Query is <Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Engagement"></FieldRef><Value Type="Lookup">106;#ABC Ltd - 31/03/2016 - Year End</Value></Eq></Where></Query>

        var viewFields = '<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Budget_x0020_hours" /><FieldRef Name="Actual_x0020_hours" />';
            viewFields += '</ViewFields>';

        var NewBudgetTotal = 0.00;
        var NewActualTotal = 0.00;
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "Work tracker - Products",
            webURL: "/sites/UKIAsuDataAnalytics",
            CAMLViewFields: viewFields,
            CAMLQuery: query,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                console.log("---------------------");
                console.log(status);
                console.log(xData.responseText);
                console.log("---------------------");
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function() {
                    console.log('Processing list of returned CAML items');
                    if($(this).attr("ows_Budget_x0020_hours")) {
                        NewBudgetTotal += Number(parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Budget_x0020_hours").split(";#")[0],2).toFixed(2));
                    }
                    if($(this).attr("ows_Actual_x0020_hours")) {
                        NewActualTotal += Number(parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Actual_x0020_hours").split(";#")[0],2).toFixed(2));

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

If I comment out the query the XML responses coming back are like the below, and you can see the Engagement field should match:

```
    "<z:row ows_Budget_x0020_hours='3.00000000000000' ows_Actual_x0020_hours='0' ows_MetaInfo='80;#' ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1' ows_ID='80' 
    ows_UniqueId='80;#{E91295D7-EF93-4F11-B486-E00F6A6AB7DF}' ows_owshiddenversion='16' ows_FSObjType='80;#0' ows_Created='2016-07-13 10:17:15' ows_PermMask='0x7fffffffffffffff' ows_Modified='2016-08-26 18:58:30' 
    ows_Engagement='106;#ABC Ltd - 31/03/2016 - Year End' ows_FileRef='80;#sites/MySite/Lists/Work Tracker  Tools/80_.000' />"
```

I have tried all sorts of changes to the query for the content of "Engagement" but nothing helps. Any thoughts?

(Please don't blame me on design here - I am trying to patch up some Sharepoint "work" done by a colleague. I am certainly not the best person to do the patchup, as much as they weren't the person do to the work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup columns should be queried differently

**By Value**

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Engagement'  />
        <Value Type='Lookup'>" + ParentEngagementText + "</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```

**By Id**

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Engagement' LookupId='TRUE'  />
        <Value Type='Lookup'>" + ParentEngagementID + "</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```